# To find sender email address in SP 2010

Tags: email, site-mailboxes

How to find the sender email address in SP 2010?
The workflow sends in email but i need to figure out the sender address.

Thanks in advance.

Devi

Comment: THank you,

I figured that out but in our workflow we get email from name From : XYZ but i couldn't figure out where actually it is given because it was not specified in the from address in the configure outgoing email.Could you guide me on that.

Answer (score 0):

This is configured in central administration, system settins, configure outgoing email, from address

Comment: THank you, I figured that out but in our workflow we get email from name From : XYZ but i couldn't figure out where actually it is given because it was not specified in the from address in the configure outgoing email.Could you guide me on that.

Comment: Normally it should use address configured in From address. Can you try updating from address and send a fresh mail using workflow

Comment: If i add a from address then the previous referred name wouldn't effect. I mean it was coming from XYZ if i add ABC then will it not display as ABC-XYZ?